# String is null when rotate screen

Tags: java, android, null, rotation, screen

I'm try too restore string value, when screen is rotate, but it's always null.

```
public class Main_screen extends Activity {
    TextView t;
    String path, ext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            path = savedInstanceState.getString(path);
            ext = savedInstanceState.getString(ext);
            t.setText(getString(R.string.selected) + "\n" + path + "\n\n" + getString(R.string.unpr_new) + "\n" + path + ext);
        }
    }
```

When I rotate device, path and ext is null.
Need I save string manualy? Or it's saved automatic when rotate in savedinstance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this if in the Manifest file you declaring

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

if you declared this flag, the activity will not be destroyed and recreated and the callback

and override this method :==>> onConfigurationChanged()

will be called.

Comment: Damn, I'm an idiot. I read about the decision earlier, but it did not work, it turns out I just made ​​a mistake in "Change" while editing manifest.

Comment: full solution here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android

Comment: @user114904 Yes..this is perfect solution...and thanx for accepting answer